# Hyperledger Caliper doen´t bind on fabric network

Tags: testing, hyperledger-fabric, benchmarking, hyperledger-caliper

Today when trying to run a benchmark on the existing Hyperledger Fabric network, which was running normally and generating results, I came across the following error when binding the network through the following command:

```
npx caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric:2.2
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ubuntu@node1:~/caliper/caliper-benchmarks/caliper-monitor$ npx caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric:2.2
undefined
undefined
undefined

                                  !             H|H|H|H|H           H__________________________________             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|§|∞|§|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H|---------------------------------|          ===============        H|---------------------------------|            /| _   _ |          H|---------------------------------|            (| O   O |)          H|---------------------------------|            /|   U   |          H-----------------------------------             |  =/  |           H              _..._/            H              _|I/|_            H      _______/| H |/_______    H     /           / /          H    |          | | /         |  H    |          ||o||          |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H   Carl Pilcher  
t̵̷̹̯̼̼̲̰̝̩͙̝͇ͫ̒͆̽͆ͥ̅͟ȩ̢͎̝͍̜̗̻͉̮̰͎̣̲͙͙̭̜͖͓̮͉̝̲̗̗̻̘͔̫̲̬̞̹̺̻̬̌ͥ͌̈͆ͫ͆ͭ̔͛͌ͦ̽̊͜ͅs̵̷͍̫̰̖͓̠͔̜̘̣̞̱͖̞̱̘͇̜̥̗͓̹̖̞̪͔̝̠̲͇̯̻̱̜̫͍̬̮̹̖̣̯̞̠͕̠̗̯̩͖̫͖̠̥̟͍͙̲̽̓ͣͦ̓̔ͭ͛̂̂̄ͯ̌ͭ̓ͪ̄ͭ̀̕͝ͅͅţ̢̪͍͔͔̹̯͉̹̪̖̳̗͉̱̠̖̲̘̰͖͙̘̼̝͔̘̼̩̹̲̹̰͔̱͇̯̺̼͈̖̠͎̫͚͓̜̰̻ͩ̔̅̾̉͛͋ͮ̋͘ͅͅĩ̴̢̯̮̙̪̗̣̞̖̬̦̞̼͎͕̱̭̺̳̗̑ͤͤ̈̌ͣ̃͢ͅn͕̖̖̼̣̖̦̜̜͚̼̩̺̞̜͍͓̹͍̯̗͓͔̣̺̲͚̮̬̘̭̪͖̖̭͖͉̫̩̼̟̲̝̳̬̟̺̬̠̰̼͉͖̟͕͍̭ͭ̿͑͛̋ͪ͆̓ͮ̏́ͤ̇̔ͪͯ́̚͜͟͝ͅḡ̒̓͐̇͐̋ͮͦ̊̋̅̚ ҉̷̖̗̙̣̮͈̭͔̣̳̲̠̹̼͈͚̦̳͈̹͎̟̰͚̮͔̖̰̙͉͉̖̫̗̬͎̠̥̞̤̘̬͙̗̫͔̼̳͍̞͍͕͕͔͙̝̞̭͟͟͡ͅͅͅ ̨̫̲͈̮͓̻͔̟͕̮̦̯͚͚̮̫̹͚̻͙͎̠̺͓͕͇͙̱̗̥̲̍̊̎͊͐̂ͭͨ̅̚͡ͅͅt̨̨̨̘͕̰͇̱̼͙̹̼̬̪̞̞̼͕͍̤̺̦̙̠̦̮͖̜̲̫̳͖̯̭̟͓̰̜̼̯̩̲͈̱̼͒̔͛̎ͪ̓͗̍ͦ͒̅ͩ̈͐ͤ̏e̷̖̗̟̦̖͇̯̖͉̖̯̭̼̜̬͕̯̥͉̠̩̳͈͓̭̘̳̘̻̪͙̣͎̟̣͍̤̺̲̤͇̜̥̦͊̈̀́̓͌̇̑̂̈ͬͣ̅͐̽̃͝ͅͅs̨̧̮̘͉̣̺̲̞͋́ͫ̔͢ͅt̝̱̣̯̲̠͚͍͈̩͉̖̝̦̘̣̫͉̮̰̼͙̠̟̻̱͓͍̦̯̳̬̻̲̝̰̩͎͒̎ͦ̂̾̔̓̇̊͆̒̃̐ͪ̅̕͟͠ͅͅȉ̸͛͗̍ͦ͐ͭ̿͝͝ ҉̥̗̲̰̖̯̱̹͔̻̟͍̖͈̠̗͉̝̦̭̩̬̫̤̮͈̭̥̱̱̬͕͔̣͉̱͓͈̮̰̰̣͓ͅͅň̉͌ͪͤ͗̊̔ͥ͋͌ ҉̨͚̱̠͇̪̩̻̲̗͕̘̣͍͈̪̣̪͖̣͕̰͇̘̠̣̝̙̟̭̩͇̦͚͎͍̟͉̣͖͖̱̀͢͠ģ̭̰̖̞͈̝̱̻̳̰̲͚͉͓͚̎̈̅͒ͦ̚͜͞ͅ ̸͓͔̪̙͎̬̮̹̰̝̲̝͇̳̝̮̫̰̥͉̭̬̙̟̞̮͚̯͎̹̻̬͔̜͙̯̻̖̭͚̭̤̞̲̠̭͍̱̳̞̯̥̱̣͙̟͇͉̩̩̘̬͉̮̒͛̀̄͐͒ͪ̍̔̚͟͠ͅͅt̵̛̙͖̺̻̹͚͎͕̝̤̠͎̙̮̠̰̰̠̫͕̜̘̞̮̪̳̳̘͇ͯͦͥ̍̆̅̅̾ͧ̍̆̍ͮͪͯͥͧ͜͡͠ë͚̣͖̝͎̘̥̦̻̟̹̟̳̖̺̩̻̞͆͂̈̈̒̓͌̆ͩͪ͐̽ͭ͛́͢͝ͅs̡̠̰̞̬̫̭̺̟̦͖̼̣̤͉͈̞͇͎̖͎͚̹͚͉͓̬̹̙̣͓̺͖̥̬̱̻̝͖͎̯̱̥͚̝̝̣̣̗͈̯̲͓̞̰͕̗̮͙̣̅ͭ͂͌̔̀͜ͅt̷̨̢̧̢͍̖̝͉̫̖̱̻̥͚̜̠̗̬̘͉̼̼̖̠̺͉̘̟͉̹̫̗̖̘̯̭̞͕̙̼͖͉̥̺̘̣͓̥̗̩̬̘͕͙̗̩̟͓̻̜͓̗̩̗̭̜̎͌͗ͩ̓͌ͤ̈͐̑̒͌ͤͬͯͅͅi̵͚̫̫̪̞͇̺̦̭͉͈ͩ̃͊͗ͭͣͦ͆́ņ̮̩͙͈̤̹̺̗̲͕̖̯͙͈͎̠̜̖̖̮͖̟͖̰̙̩̞̖͓̖̺̹̱͓̗̠̪̦̤̖̲̊̑̎́̄͌̿̕ͅͅͅg̛̬͇̘̹̳̟͎̱̣͕̣̤̦̝͖̮̻̰͚̬̯͕̘̖͔̘̲̦̲͖͇̮̥͇̯̰͇̭̣̭̖̼̱͙̣̞̦̠̤̖͚ͩ̿̈͐͐ͣ͆̔̿͋ͥ̽̊͛ͭ͋̏̌̏́ͅͅ ̵͚̬̭͇̩̯͎̞̟̺͓̝̯͍̯͎͉͙͈͌͛ͣ̇̔͘͝ͅt̶̛̟̰̯̦̙͚͚̘͙̟̤̱̬͎͈̟̹̙̫̘̣͍̼̼̱̮̱͆͆̃̏̍̑̒́̋ͭͩͯͭ͘͞ͅͅe̶̷̼͙̭̫̼͖͕̲̤͍͕̺͍͕̲̣̭̭̥̹͚̰̺̙̖̦̟̘̙̟̪̞͔̳͚͎̺̠̺͑̽̏̆ͨ̽̈̌ͮ͆̽ͯͣ̀ͣͦ̒̽̈͜͝ͅs̸̴̝̦̥̩̥͎̮̬͉̙̙̘̳̰̰ͧ̊͂ͧ̍͋͑̒ͧͨ̾͛̋͐́ͅt̷̨͕̲̫͖̥̖̥̙̜͙̜͉̗̝͎̪͈͍̳̱̦͎̍͗ͩ̋͑ͧͩ̈̆̾ͭͥ͆̿͡͝į̓̊͐̒ͫ͂̽̆͗̽ͩ̇ͭ̓͌ͬ͆ ҉̸͇̗̖̣͓̪̘̭̺͕̟̯̺̙͔̮̞̞̹̼̟̘̹̺̭͚͔͕̫̪̖̩̳͖̦̝̜͉̞̘͎̘̻̙͓̺͍͇͕̼̕ͅn̛͙̥͍̲̙̱̫͖̜͔̫̮̱̣̜͈͔̠̯͕͈͉͔͓̫͍̠͕̖̬̖̠̝̱̺̪̗̮͖͇̭̗͖̬͇̻̭̥̮̘͈̭̭͉͑̓ͦ͐̈ͯ̎̓͂̍̍̈͆ͣ̎ͯͮͫ͢͟͞g̷̨̱̹̻̳̠̦̱̼͙͔̰̮͙̭̜͉̤̰̜̳̭̲͕̗̬̩̖̟̝̰̙̣̳̲̰̺͉͎̝ͫ̓ͬ̀̏̊̽̾̕͠͝ͅͅͅ ̢̨̞̯̖͍̤̥͙̬̪̌̿ͯ͋̃͌̚̕͘͠t̵̨̗̯̹͍̪̞̼̬̻̥̘̠̭͖̬̥͕̲̠̫͎͉̦̪̻̠̱̙͋ͨͤ̀͆ͣ͑̚e͚͓̲͉̲̫̳̪̝͉̣̖͉̹͔̦͚ͥͫ̑̔͌ͪ͑́͝s̢͔̥̖̜̣̘͇͕̞̘̥̻͔͎̟͇̟̳̩̟̤͉̙͇͔̝͕̞̰̻̜̟͎̲̼̠̠̰̖̖̦̅ͣͯ͋̊́ͦ͛͝t̗̦̦̲͇̣͈̯͚̖͍̤͎͔̗̱̟̪̺̣̖̱̪͖̫͕͍̳̰͙͔͖̩̎̅ͪ̓͗ͦ̌ͣ̾̅̔ͫ̄ͣ̀̇ͨ̽̓̕͘̕͟ͅi̸ͩ̐̋̅̊̈͐̌̂̓̄̋̒͒̀ ҉̢͈͙͙͔̮̜̲̞̗͎̠͔̮̦͔̘͉̳̞̹̘̫͙̼̞͔͎͖̪͔͠ͅͅͅn̢̢̗͖͉͓̝̗̩̻̳̖͚̤͕̮̯̼̗͉̘̰̙̹̙̖͆́̔́̾͢g̵̫̥̞̠͓̲͙͚̦̠̣̱̱̺̺̹̣͈̙̞̬͎̻̳̞͚̳̻̖̱͖̩̳̲͓̞̤̯͖͓̝̯̙͎̜̤̘̙̤̺̊ͯ̅̑̏̎ͥ̏́͌̒ͨͨ̇̃͒͊͆́̀͡͝ͅͅ ̷̬̫̫̰̦̘̬̖͉͔͙̟̭̳̘̱͚͉̠͔̥̩̼͉̭̱̯̟̹͉̞͚̤̟͊̔̉̇̋̈͟ͅt̶̡̔ͫͭ̾̄̃̾̄̒̔ͩ̀̇̓ ҉̶̭͇͓̳̦̟̲͠ȅ̛͍̥̗̜͈̦͙̫̱͎͖̯̪͔̪̤̜̣̦̘̟̦͓̜̱ͤ̅̍͗̿͂͆̄ͮͫ̈ͩͥ͘ş̢̬̗̣̻̯͎͙̠̜͉̜̠̬̭͍͓̬̜̜̼ͥͯͬ̎͒ͭ̀ͦ̋͊̄́͢͢t̵̖̫̩̳͉̪̭̱̮̞͉͈̯͉̟͇̭͎͍͍͈̻̺͉̳͓̜̘̥̥̳̰̜̙͎͕̟̆͌ͧ͐̿̿̓͛͑͒̾̃̚̕i̺͖̹̭̙͉̙̗̦̫̥͖͉̱̼͈̼͖̫̲̥̼̰͕͙͙͉̗̩̰͙͖͎͉͚̜̮̘̳̟̼͚̺̙̦͉͉̳̞̬̫͔̟͈̤͚̹̅̋ͮ͑̊̀̀͟͞ͅͅn̶̴̡͎̼̯̞̠̹̗̦̯̥̫̻̯̙͇̱̭̯̻̺͚̹̖̞̯͉͈̺̥̝̗̪̟̮̻̤̦̭̫͕͉͇̣̲̻̼̭͉̖͈̹͔̳̮̤̝̙͈͖̂̈̃͊̈ͤ̈͐ͪ͒ͥͧ͂̂͊ͥͅͅg̶͉̞̤̳̼̯͉̟͖̹̤̘̬̲͚͈͍͍̥̪͍͇̝̭̦̺̝̥͙̗͙̰̊ͪ̉͐ͫ͛̊ͧͮ͋̌̈̉͗̋͡ͅ ̴̛̫͖̟̯̞̗͎̳͇͚̮͎̰̗͎͖̯̜̖̪̤̥̲̼͙͖͖̼̊ͤ̍͊̽̿͆̓̊̈͜ͅͅt̶̸̗͔̖̝̞̥̫̼̖̱̟̰̻̼̦͓̱̞̯̝̩̟̩̭̟̻̣̦͕̮̩̼̦͔̜̗̥̓͐͛̔͊̀ͅȩ̸̴̧̛̣͚͖̖̱̪̤̞̲̜̘̖̫̫̫͈͕͚̠̲͖̘͓̥̳̹͈̳̤̣̬̮̳̝̣̟͔̰͎͉̦͍̜͚̬̤͎̦̪̖̘̦̹̟̠̻̜͎̤̱̱̺ͭ̍̉ͩ͊ͥ̋ͣ̓̅ͅͅs̹̲̠̖͈̞̦̱͇͓͖͇͙ͯͤ̉̈̒̔̀̽̾̆ͪ́̒͋̎̚͢͢ͅͅt̴̵̞̯͙͍͍͙̗̘̟̳͉͕̮̖̯̪̮̪̘̲̪̳̰̞̰̺̦̤̦͚̖̟̞̪̥̩̯̺͙͔͔̼̖̜̗͗̆̈͋͆ͪͮ͆̏ͩ̍̑͛ͫ̃ͩ͟͞ͅi̢̤̮̫̼̦͇̠͓̖̣͇͔̣̗̥̞͖͙̻̩͍̰̩̘̜̰̪̤͎̼͕̳̘̟͇͕̙̻̝̲̥̰̦̹̲͍̝ͪ̑͌̈̒͛̅̓ͮ̂͂ͭ́́̉̋ͯ͒͟͟͜͠ͅͅn͒̈͊͋ ҉̶̸̨̖͎͈̤̮̖̘͍̺̯̳͙̰͕̤͈͠ͅg̷̨̬̣̯̰̠̫̪͍̪̻̫̝͉̐͆ͯ̿̀̉̒ͨ̚͝͠ͅ
```

The container log during command execution is as follows:

```
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> DEBU 25ac signature for identity 0 validated
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25ad 0xc002d730c0 gate 1641843441662391079 evaluation starts
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25ae 0xc002d730c0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25af 0xc002d730c0 processing identity 0 - &{Org2MSP fa3ff8b9f156ffd6b52dd89cbb9bf68404142492395309efd818ce7598d460fa}
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b0 0xc002d730c0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is not an admin under this MSP [Org2MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [Org2MSP]
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b1 0xc002d730c0 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b2 0xc002d730c0 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b3 0xc002d730c0 processing identity 0 - &{Org2MSP fa3ff8b9f156ffd6b52dd89cbb9bf68404142492395309efd818ce7598d460fa}
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b4 0xc002d730c0 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b5 0xc002d730c0 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b6 0xc002d730c0 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25b7 0xc002d730c0 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25b8 0xc002d730c0 gate 1641843441662391079 evaluation succeeds
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25b9 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25ba == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25bb Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25bc == Done Evaluating *policies.ImplicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [gossip.comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> DEBU 25bd Authenticated 192.169.0.10:7051
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 25be [core]Channel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 25bf [core]Subchannel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 25c0 Obtaining identity
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 25c1 Could not connect to Endpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : peer0.org2.example.com:7051 isn't in our organization, cannot be a bootstrap peer
2022-01-10 19:37:21.662 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 25c2 [transport]transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2022-01-10 19:37:22.019 UTC [gossip.channel] publishStateInfo -> DEBU 25c3 Empty membership, no one to publish state info to
2022-01-10 19:37:22.221 UTC [gossip.election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 25c4 cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Exiting
2022-01-10 19:37:22.221 UTC [gossip.election] IsLeader -> DEBU 25c5 cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Returning true
2022-01-10 19:37:22.221 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 25c6 Sign: plaintext: 120A6368616E6E656C616C6C1804A201...0D08D482AEE980E6BFE41610A0011801 
2022-01-10 19:37:22.221 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 25c7 Sign: digest: A6E78994CE1A4DC212EC86121EEBA4A510A8528F19138B4CD21ECD7DF248B8FF 
2022-01-10 19:37:22.221 UTC [gossip.election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 25c8 cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Entering
2022-01-10 19:37:24.170 UTC [gossip.discovery] InitiateSync -> DEBU 25c9 No peers to send to, aborting membership sync
2022-01-10 19:37:24.439 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 25ca unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2022-01-10T19:37:26.439Z grpc.peer_address=192.169.0.11:48962 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=172.265µs
2022-01-10 19:37:24.441 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 25cb Sign: plaintext: 180172DB060A20CC8E48A9881F1D88FC...455254494649434154452D2D2D2D2D0A 
2022-01-10 19:37:24.441 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 25cc Sign: digest: 4FD8C83279FDBC744FD6C298C79FDE45ECA93276DC25210E71A8BBD98B7A3C2D 
2022-01-10 19:37:24.442 UTC [gossip.comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> DEBU 25cd Sending GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY conn:<pki_id:"\314\216H\251\210\037\035\210\374D;\250oa\030\223\237\271O\203\237\314\346\376R\010zR\323~\344L" identity:"\n\007Org1MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n9/xWAeAFaSnqVfsn7GytPrbgUJUApAKyhqBy2g==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" > , Envelope: 864 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes to 192.169.0.11:48962
2022-01-10 19:37:24.442 UTC [gossip.comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> DEBU 25ce Received pki_id:"\272n\361v\0008\312\205\252\206\256o\022G\267\202\251\035\227c0\305\243\332\002b\366F\017\rP\032" identity:"\n\007Org3MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nAnG4pqS3sOUaZLh5QfnmdIEFOaEsR7hMzrBxtQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" probe:true  from 192.169.0.11:48962
2022-01-10 19:37:24.442 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 25cf Obtaining identity
2022-01-10 19:37:24.444 UTC [peer.gossip.mcs] getValidatedIdentity -> DEBU 25d0 Validation succeeded {"CN":"peer0.org3.example.com","Issuer-CN":"ca.org3.example.com","Issuer-L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","Issuer-OU":null,"L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","MSP":"Org3MSP","OU":["peer"]} on [channelall]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.444 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 25d1 Obtaining identity
2022-01-10 19:37:24.444 UTC [peer.gossip.mcs] getValidatedIdentity -> DEBU 25d2 Validation succeeded {"CN":"peer0.org3.example.com","Issuer-CN":"ca.org3.example.com","Issuer-L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","Issuer-OU":null,"L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","MSP":"Org3MSP","OU":["peer"]} on [channelall]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 25d3 Obtaining identity
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [peer.gossip.mcs] getValidatedIdentity -> DEBU 25d4 Validation succeeded {"CN":"peer0.org3.example.com","Issuer-CN":"ca.org3.example.com","Issuer-L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","Issuer-OU":null,"L-ST-C":"[San Francisco]-[]-[US]","MSP":"Org3MSP","OU":["peer"]} on [channelall]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [peer.gossip.mcs] VerifyByChannel -> DEBU 25d5 Got policy manager for channel [channelall]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [peer.gossip.mcs] VerifyByChannel -> DEBU 25d6 Got reader policy for channel [channelall] with flag [true]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25d7 == Evaluating *policies.ImplicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers ==
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25d8 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25d9 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Readers ==
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 25da Verify: digest = 00000000  2e 51 12 d7 0a c7 b3 5e  60 82 06 ce fe f8 c8 e6  |.Q.....^`.......|
00000010  03 e1 ff 02 07 9a 6f 46  26 26 29 7d f4 92 35 72  |......oF&&)}..5r|
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 25db Verify: sig = 00000000  30 45 02 21 00 f2 59 1d  f6 3e cd cb 97 9f fc b3  |0E.!..Y..>......|
00000010  2a 38 dc 1e e8 09 9f 7d  1a 01 ca 82 cb f1 e0 ee  |*8.....}........|
00000020  e2 50 78 04 bf 02 20 78  af 73 b6 70 44 ac eb 6b  |.Px... x.s.pD..k|
00000030  b4 6a f9 33 b2 d7 bd 93  9e c8 30 fb 30 98 56 d5  |.j.3......0.0.V.|
00000040  64 5e 58 f7 a2 f8 31                              |d^X...1|
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> DEBU 25dc signature for identity 0 validated
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25dd 0xc002dddb70 gate 1641843444445860228 evaluation starts
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25de 0xc002dddb70 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25df 0xc002dddb70 processing identity 0 - &{Org3MSP d77b61d2843232217d9e6619fe1e46cb73c3e3fda953d3e651a6198b8165db4a}
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e0 0xc002dddb70 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected Org2MSP, got Org3MSP)
2022-01-10 19:37:24.445 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e1 0xc002dddb70 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e2 0xc002dddb70 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e3 0xc002dddb70 processing identity 0 - &{Org3MSP d77b61d2843232217d9e6619fe1e46cb73c3e3fda953d3e651a6198b8165db4a}
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e4 0xc002dddb70 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected Org2MSP, got Org3MSP)
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e5 0xc002dddb70 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e6 0xc002dddb70 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e7 0xc002dddb70 processing identity 0 - &{Org3MSP d77b61d2843232217d9e6619fe1e46cb73c3e3fda953d3e651a6198b8165db4a}
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e8 0xc002dddb70 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected Org2MSP, got Org3MSP)
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25e9 0xc002dddb70 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25ea 0xc002dddb70 gate 1641843444445860228 evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25eb Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25ec == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25ed == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org3MSP/Readers ==
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 25ee Verify: digest = 00000000  2e 51 12 d7 0a c7 b3 5e  60 82 06 ce fe f8 c8 e6  |.Q.....^`.......|
00000010  03 e1 ff 02 07 9a 6f 46  26 26 29 7d f4 92 35 72  |......oF&&)}..5r|
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 25ef Verify: sig = 00000000  30 45 02 21 00 f2 59 1d  f6 3e cd cb 97 9f fc b3  |0E.!..Y..>......|
00000010  2a 38 dc 1e e8 09 9f 7d  1a 01 ca 82 cb f1 e0 ee  |*8.....}........|
00000020  e2 50 78 04 bf 02 20 78  af 73 b6 70 44 ac eb 6b  |.Px... x.s.pD..k|
00000030  b4 6a f9 33 b2 d7 bd 93  9e c8 30 fb 30 98 56 d5  |.j.3......0.0.V.|
00000040  64 5e 58 f7 a2 f8 31                              |d^X...1|
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> DEBU 25f0 signature for identity 0 validated
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25f1 0xc002df0cb0 gate 1641843444446538998 evaluation starts
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f2 0xc002df0cb0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f3 0xc002df0cb0 processing identity 0 - &{Org3MSP d77b61d2843232217d9e6619fe1e46cb73c3e3fda953d3e651a6198b8165db4a}
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f4 0xc002df0cb0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is not an admin under this MSP [Org3MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [Org3MSP]
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f5 0xc002df0cb0 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f6 0xc002df0cb0 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f7 0xc002df0cb0 processing identity 0 - &{Org3MSP d77b61d2843232217d9e6619fe1e46cb73c3e3fda953d3e651a6198b8165db4a}
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f8 0xc002df0cb0 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25f9 0xc002df0cb0 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25fa 0xc002df0cb0 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 25fb 0xc002df0cb0 principal evaluation fails
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 25fc 0xc002df0cb0 gate 1641843444446538998 evaluation succeeds
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25fd Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Org3MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25fe == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org3MSP/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 25ff Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 2600 == Done Evaluating *policies.ImplicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [gossip.comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> DEBU 2601 Authenticated 192.169.0.11:48962
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [gossip.comm] GossipStream -> INFO 2602 Peer ba6ef1760038ca85aa86ae6f1247b782a91d976330c5a3da0262f6460f0d501a (192.169.0.11:48962) probed us
2022-01-10 19:37:24.446 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 2603 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2022-01-10T19:37:34.441Z grpc.peer_address=192.169.0.11:48962 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5.592517ms
2022-01-10 19:37:24.447 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 2604 [transport]transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2022-01-10 19:37:26.019 UTC [gossip.channel] publishStateInfo -> DEBU 2605 Empty membership, no one to publish state info to
2022-01-10 19:37:26.166 UTC [gossip.discovery] periodicalSendAlive -> DEBU 2606 Empty membership, no one to send a heartbeat to
2022-01-10 19:37:26.167 UTC [gossip.discovery] periodicalSendAlive -> DEBU 2607 Sleeping 5s
2022-01-10 19:37:27.221 UTC [gossip.election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 2608 cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Exiting
2022-01-10 19:37:27.222 UTC [gossip.election] IsLeader -> DEBU 2609 cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Returning true
2022-01-10 19:37:27.222 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 260a Sign: plaintext: 120A6368616E6E656C616C6C1804A201...0D08D482AEE980E6BFE41610A1011801 
2022-01-10 19:37:27.223 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 260b Sign: digest: CC97B8E2007D3FB292AADA6FA3C7E8091AEA5D5EB77AEF238E5D7E8A165B74B1 
2022-01-10 19:37:27.223 UTC [gossip.election] waitForInterrupt -> DEBU 260c cc8e48a9881f1d88fc443ba86f6118939fb94f839fcce6fe52087a52d37ee44c : Entering
2022-01-10 19:37:28.170 UTC [gossip.discovery] InitiateSync -> DEBU 260d No peers to send to, aborting membership sync
```

As you can see, special characters are being returned in the output, and intermittently, looking like the command is in a loop.
Remembering that the fabric network is working normally accepting requests.
The command was executed several times during this week running everything correctly, and when executing it this morning I got this error.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This issue https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/2235 describes the events that caused what you are seeing, hopefully the problem has been resolved now. Certainly an unusual thing to occur.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this issue setting the colors version to 1.4.0.